# How to deal with the "platform specific dynamic library" problem with uploading to PyPI?

Tags: python, pypi, dynamic-library, binaries, language-interoperability

I have a Python package that depends on binaries. I've build the linux version and it is available on PyPI. The key was setting the `package_data` argument to ensure the `*.so` files were also uploaded to PyPI.

Now I want to do the same thing with Windows, which obviously require `*.dll` dependencies, rather than `*.so`. When uploading my package to PyPI, is it possible to upload `*.so` files for when a user downloads my package on a linux platform and `*.dll` files for when a user is on windows. The issue I'm foreseeing is that if I have to upload all binaries for all platforms, my package will quickly exceed the size limit for PyPI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [compatibility tags for built distributions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/) are for.

For example, consider https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files. It publishes the following wheels:

- `numpy-1.18.5-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl`
- `numpy-1.18.5-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_i686.whl`
- `numpy-1.18.5-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`
- `numpy-1.18.5-cp38-cp38-win32.whl`
- `numpy-1.18.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`

Each of these contain the platform-specific dependencies for the given platform.